# Angular JS - “Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate:”?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to take a image form API, but I am geeting error "Angular JS - “Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate:”".

**Here is my code :**

**service Js code:**

```
    .factory('Comment', function($http) {

        return {
        image : function(id){
                        return $http.get(server + 'api/image/' + id); 
                    }
        }
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.image = function () {
                Comment.image(id)
                .success(function(data){});
              }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container"  ng-controller="mainController" >
<div class="row" ng-repeat="q in qa.data" >
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col.sm.12" >
        <div class="artist-data pull-left" style = "background-color:#BEB7B7;">
            <!-- Div for user image -->
            <div class="artst-pic pull-left" >
                <img width = 100px; height:60px; ng-src="{{image(q.userID)}}"  alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
```

But I am geeting the error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bimage(q.userID)%7D%7D&p1=ReferenceError%3A%20id%20is%20not%20defined
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:6:447
    at q (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:73:428)
    at pre (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:57:412)
    at B (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:49:261)
    at h (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:43:24)
    at h (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:43:41)
    at h (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:43:41)
    at h (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:43:41)
    at h (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test_QA/vender/angular.min.js:43:41)
```

Please tell me what is this error?

Comment: Where does `q.userID` come from? I'm willing to bet that's your problem.

Comment: Should it be `$scope.image = function (id) {`?

Comment: It's complaining about `id` not being defined. You're missing `id` as an argument to your `$scope.image` function.

Comment: $scope.image = function (id) {
                Comment.image()
                .success(function(data){});
              }, I tried and pass id to $scope.image but it is not working, because I have to pass "id" to Comment.image() to communicate with service code

Comment: Pass the parameter to this $scope.image = function (id)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `image` function declaration should look like this:

```
$scope.image = function (id) {
    Comment.image(id)
           .success(function (data) {});
};
```

Comment: tried like this also but not working, If I am giving "id" like this  then I am not able to load page....

Comment: When I try same thing then id is repeated and it is not stopping,  I check it through console log........I don't know why it is happening .........

Comment: @AnitaMehta: Could you provide a fiddle or plunkr ? It's not clear what you mean by _"id is repeated and it is not stopping"_ (nor should it happen).

Comment: I mean the scope.image function is repeatedly getting called.I can see the id value continuously being printed in console.